# Visual Studio App Center - find diagnostic log by time

Tags: azure-application-insights, visual-studio-app-center

We have an Xamarin App with Visual Studio App Center integration, which has a crash hard to track down based on our internal logs.

The App Center account is configured to export it's data to Azure Application Insights for better insights on the data.

However, in AppInsights I see only custom events, no failures, although there are a lot of crashes in errors reported in App Center Diagnostics section.

The issues in diagnostics are grouped, but is there a way to find the logged data from a crash/error by time? Based on our internal logs, we know the time of the issue, but would like to check if some crash was logged in that time to App Center, is there a way to check it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the official [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/analytics/export), it looks like Azure Application Insights does not explicitly log the "Crash" data, as done in Azure Blob Storage.

This same requirement has been logged as a Feature Request [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/appcenter/issues/339) and [here](https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter/issues/984), that discusses the need in much greater detail. Please feel free to express your interest in getting this implemented by our internal Teams by elaborating the need and priority, and upvoting the request. Here is the Product's [Roadmap](https://github.com/Microsoft/appcenter/wiki/Roadmap) to track.

Meanwhile, here are the alternatives that I can think of, at the moment:

- [Switch to Azure Blob Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/analytics/export#azure-blob-storage) (I know it's tough to make a switch when you already are on a different solution, but this is just an available option)
- [Call specific APIs for specific crash/error information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/gdpr/diagnostics-export#call-our-apis-for-specific-crasherror-information)
- More about fetching the events surrounding a crash [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/diagnostics/features)
- [Errors](https://openapi.appcenter.ms/#/errors) and [Export](https://openapi.appcenter.ms/#/export) API definitions to explore

Hope this helps!